# Iterating and asigning with LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, spring, jsf-2, spring-jdbc

I have `LinkedHashMap<String,List<SelectItem>> results` = got the results from DB see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20950571/spring-jdbc-template-how-to-retrieve-multiple-result-with-multiple-parameters-w)

I need to assign the above results to the lists available in UI using for loop.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<SelectItem>> entry : results.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        List<SelectItem> values = entry.getValue();
        System.out.println("Key = " + key);
        System.out.println("Values = " + values + "n");
}
```

Assigning part example :

```
if(key.equalsIgnoreCase("getProjectManager")) {
        tempselectedProjMgrList = entry.getValue();                             
}
```

Based on the key I am adding the values to a diff list like the one i said in the given link above.

The above sys out does not print the acutal values inside the list instead it prints like the one given below ..

```
Key = getProjectManager
Values = [javax.faces.model.SelectItem@fadb0a,javax.faces.model.SelectItem@1245c45]n
Key = getResourceOwnerSE
Values = [javax.faces.model.SelectItem@25f52c, javax.faces.model.SelectItem@323fc] <br/>
```

How to get the actual values from the above list.

Comment: Answered in: [Printing Java collections nicely (toString doesn't return pretty output)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395401/printing-java-collections-nicely-tostring-doesnt-return-pretty-output)

Comment: I tried that too  but its not working for me.Is there any other option to iterate and get the list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SelectItem` did'nt override the `toString()` method herited from the `Object` class which is :

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

That's why you get such an output.

So you'll have to loop through all the values and call [`getValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/model/SelectItem.html#getValue%28%29). That will call the `toString()` method on the value object hold by the `SelectItem`.

```
System.out.println("Key = " + key);
System.out.println("Values = "); 
for(SelectItem st : values){
    System.out.print(st.getValue()+" ");
}
System.out.println();
```

**EDIT:**

If you want directly to get the appropriated list with the key associated, just do

`tempselectedResOwnSeList = results.get("getProjectManager");`

Comment: Thanks its printing correctly!!.But based on the keys I have to assign the values to different list ex: xxlist,yylist,zzlist.But from the DB I have already retrieved the list and put them into the hashmap and brought it into UI.But why do I have to again iterate and get the values don't I have any other option to get the list directly? Instead iterating ?Please advise

Comment: Thanks its printing correctly!!.But based on the keys I have to assign the values to different list ex: xxlist,yylist,zzlist.But from the DB I have already retrieved the list and put them into the hashmap and brought it into UI.But why do I have to again iterate and get the values don't I have any other option to get the list directly? Instead iterating ?Please advise.Link for retreiving the list is [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970793/iterating-and-asigning-with-linkedhashmap)here

Comment: @techy360 What do you mean ? Please edit or ask a new question with a concrete example.

Comment: I already did List<SelectItem> getProjectManager = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();results.put("getProjectManager", getProjectManager); in the DAO and I got the results in LinkedHashMap<String,List<SelectItem>> results. Can't I able to assign the diff lists direclty like xxlist =results.getvalue() based on key  say example : if(key.equalsIgnoreCase("getResourceOwnerSE ")){tempselectedResOwnSeList = entry.getValue(); } in UI ?; instead looping ? I am trying to assign the results directly to a list.My intention is to increase the performance.

Comment: @techy360 If I understand well you can directly get the appropriated list with the key. I.e `tempselectedResOwnSeList = results.get("getProjectManager");`. The get method will give you the value for the associated key in the map.

Comment: Thats really a stupid question from me.I should have known that  results.get("getProjectManager"); will obivously give the lists.But unfortunately my mind isn't working that time.Thanks a lot ZouZou it resolved my issue.

Comment: @techy360 You're welcome! If you have a doubt, always check the doc ! http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do the below:

First create a toString method for your SelectItem class with all the info you want to be printed . For example:

```
public class SelectItem {

private int a;
private String b;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "SelectItem [a=" + a + ", b=" + b + "]";
}
```

}

then do:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<SelectItem>> entry : results.entrySet()) {
                       String key = entry.getKey();
                        List<SelectItem> values = entry.getValue();
                        System.out.println("Key = " + key);
                        System.out.print("Values = ");}
                        for (SelectItem selectItem : values){
                            System.out.print(selectItem.toString() +    "n");
                        }
}
```

Comment: I tried the above one too but I am getting  the following output                                                            Key = getProjectManager
Values = javax.faces.model.SelectItem@94e3c1njavax.faces.model.SelectItem@f4acd1njavax.faces.model.SelectItem@17e0e74njavax.faces.model.SelectItem@e71be2njavax.faces.model.SelectItem@d79805njavax.faces.model.SelectItem@3d96a6njavax.faces.model.SelectItem@16d749enjavax.faces.model.SelectItem@1034f8dnjavax.faces.model.SelectItem@5bb9aenjavax.faces.model.SelectItem@1fb6021nKey

Comment: Did you create the toString method in your SelectItem class?

Comment: SelectItem Class is in javax.jsf_1.2.0 jar and its not editable

Comment: Then you need to follow zouzou advice and use getValue()

Comment: Appreciate if you could provide me some links or URL's for the solution